# How @Autowired works with JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring Annotation and I want to know how each annotation works similair to the xml configuration.
Anyway, I want to use Spring without any xml file. So I started to use the JavaConfig.

In order to tell Spring, that we are using JavaConfig, we are using @Configuration.

Now I am just studying how the @Bean and @Autowired are working.

@Bean is for defining the bean which is similiar to the xml coniguration

```
<bean></bean>
```

Below is my sample code, which is working fine for testing @Configuration and @Bean:

```
            package com.example.service;

            public class Greeting {
               public Greeting(){
                   System.out.println("In Greeting Constructor");
               }

               public String getMessage(){
                   return "Hello Greeting Message";
               }
            }


            package com.example.config;

            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            @Configuration
            public class AnotherConfig {
                @Bean
                public Greeting getGreet(){
                    return new Greeting();
                }
            }   


            package com.example;

            import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
            import com.example.config.AnotherConfig;
            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            public class HelloApp {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context1 = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnotherConfig.class);
                    Greeting obj3 = (Greeting)context1.getBean("getGreet");
                    System.out.println("obj3 ("+obj3+")");
                    System.out.println(obj3.getMessage());
                }
            }

            Output:
            In Greeting Constructor
            obj3 (com.example.service.Greeting@3043fe0e)
            Hello Greeting Message
```

Now I want to use @Autowired in the above example:

```
            package com.example.service;

            public class Greeting {
               public Greeting(){
                   System.out.println("In Greeting Constructor");
               }

               public String getMessage(){
                   return "Hello Greeting Message";
               }
            }


            package com.example.config;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            @Configuration
            public class AnotherConfig {

                @Autowired
                Greeting greeting;

                @Bean
                public Greeting getGreet(){
                    return this.greeting;
                }
            }       


            package com.example;

            import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
            import com.example.config.AnotherConfig;
            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            public class HelloApp {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context1 = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnotherConfig.class);
                    Greeting obj3 = (Greeting)context1.getBean("getGreet");
                    System.out.println("obj3 ("+obj3+")");
                    System.out.println(obj3.getMessage());
                }
            }

            Error: Not working!!!

            Oct 15, 2016 2:49:04 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
            INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@439f5b3d: startup date [Sat Oct 15 02:49:04 SGT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
            Oct 15, 2016 2:49:05 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
            INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7d417077: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,anotherConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,getGreet]; root of factory hierarchy
            Exception in thread "main" obj3 (null)
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example.HelloApp.main(HelloApp.java:12)
```

I have googled and in one the example they have mentioned @AnnotationDrivenConfig is required for @Autowired to work, (http://www.basilv.com/psd/blog/2009/java-based-configuration-of-spring-dependency-injection)
I am using Spring 3.2, but @AnnotationDrivenConfig is not resolving and it seems not available?!!

So, I have tried other option of ComponentScan:

```
            package com.example.service;

            import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

            @Component
            public class Greeting {
               public Greeting(){
                   System.out.println("In Greeting Constructor");
               }

               public String getMessage(){
                   return "Hello Greeting Message";
               }
            }


            package com.example.config;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            @Configuration
            @ComponentScan("com.example.service")
            public class AnotherConfig {

                @Autowired  
                @Bean
                public Greeting getGreet(Greeting greeting){
                    return greeting;
                }
            }   


            package com.example;

            import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
            import com.example.config.AnotherConfig;
            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            public class HelloApp {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context1 = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnotherConfig.class);
                    Greeting obj3 = (Greeting)context1.getBean("getGreet");
                    System.out.println("obj3 ("+obj3+")");
                    System.out.println(obj3.getMessage());
                }
            }

            Output: Working with construtor injection

            In Greeting Constructor
            obj3 (com.example.service.Greeting@7a9273a8)
            Hello Greeting Message
```

But why same thing not working with property setter?

```
            package com.example.config;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

            import com.example.service.Greeting;

            @Configuration
            @ComponentScan("com.example.service")
            public class AnotherConfig {

                @Autowired  
                Greeting greeting;

                @Bean
                public Greeting getGreet(){
                    return this.greeting;
                }
            }   

            Error:
            Oct 15, 2016 2:54:41 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
            INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@439f5b3d: startup date [Sat Oct 15 02:54:41 SGT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
            Oct 15, 2016 2:54:42 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
            INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1134affc: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,anotherConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,greeting,getGreet]; root of factory hierarchy
            In Greeting Constructor
            obj3 (null)
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example.HelloApp.main(HelloApp.java:12)
```

Comment: I would skip straight to modern Spring (4.3) with Spring Boot. Note also that using `@Autowired` on fields is discouraged because it hides dependencies and leads to subtle bugs; it's better to use the constructor. As of Spring 4.3, you don't even need `@Autowired` if the bean class only has one constructor. Finally, `@Component`/`@Service` classes are *automatically* registered as beans if scanned, so you don't need the `@Bean` method if you're component-scanning them.

Comment: learn how to use Spring Boot

Comment: One more note--you don't use `@Configuration` to *tell* Spring you're using annotations, it's what Spring *looks for* once it's already using annotations, basically the equivalent of an XML file.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Problem with modern spring like SpringBoot application is, For example using SpringApplication annotation..what is does at background..it is the combination of Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration, ComponentScan annotation. when started to dig on each annotation and what it does, I ended with Autowired and couldn't understand...so many annotation doing similar things, but are different in some way..like annotation-config and component-scan..